# Mocking jenkins pipeline steps

Tags: jenkins, groovy, mocking, jenkins-pipeline

I have a class that i use in my jenkinsfile, simplified version of it here:

```
class TestBuild {
    def build(jenkins) {
        jenkins.script {
            jenkins.sh(returnStdout: true, script: "echo build")
        }
    }
}
```

And i supply `this` as a jenkins parameter when using it in the jenkinsfile. What would be the best way to mock jenkins object here that has script and sh ? 
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had similar problems the other week, I came up with this:

```
import org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScript

def mockCpsScript() {
    return [
        'sh': { arg ->
            def script
            def returnStdout
            // depending on sh is called arg is either a map or a string vector with arguments
            if (arg.length == 1 && arg[0] instanceof Map) {
                script = arg[0]['script']
                returnStdout = arg[0]['returnStdout']
            } else {
                script = arg[0]
            }
            println "Calling sh with script: ${script}"
        },
        'script' : { arg ->
              arg[0]()
        },
    ] as CpsScript
}
```

and used together with your script (extended with non-named sh call):

```
class TestBuild {
    def build(jenkins) {
        jenkins.script {
            jenkins.sh(returnStdout: true, script: "echo build")
            jenkins.sh("echo no named arguments")
        }
    }
}

def obj = new TestBuild()
obj.build(mockCpsScript())
```

it outputs:

```
[Pipeline] echo
Calling sh with script: echo build
[Pipeline] echo
Calling sh with script: echo no named arguments
```

Now this it self isn't very useful, but it easy to add logic which defines behaviour of the mock methods, for example, this version controls the contents returned by readFile depending of what directory and file is being read:

```
import org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScript

def mockCpsScript(Map<String, String> readFileMap) {
    def currentDir = null
    return [
        'dir' : { arg ->
            def dir = arg[0]
            def subClosure = arg[1]
            if (currentDir != null) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("Dir '${currentDir}' is already open, trying to open '${dir}'")
            }
            currentDir = dir
            try {
                subClosure()
            } finally {
                currentDir = null
            }
        },
        'echo': { arg ->
            println(arg[0])
        },
        'readFile' : { arg ->
            def file = arg[0]
            if (currentDir != null) {
                file = currentDir + '/' + file
            }
            def contents = readFileMap[file]
            if (contents == null) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("There is no mapped file '${file}'!")
            }
            return contents
        },
        'script' : { arg ->
              arg[0]()
        },
    ] as CpsScript
}

class TestBuild {
    def build(jenkins) {
        jenkins.script {
            jenkins.dir ('a') {
                jenkins.echo(jenkins.readFile('some.file'))
            }
            jenkins.echo(jenkins.readFile('another.file'))
        }
    }
}

def obj = new TestBuild()
obj.build(mockCpsScript(['a/some.file' : 'Contents of first file', 'another.file' : 'Some other contents']))
```

This outputs:

```
[Pipeline] echo
Contents of first file
[Pipeline] echo
Some other contents
```

If you need to use currentBuild or similar properties, then you can need to assign those after the closure coercion:

```
import org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScript

def mockCpsScript() {
    def jenkins = [
        // same as above
    ] as CpsScript
    jenkins.currentBuild = [
        // Add attributes you need here. E.g. result:
        result:null,
    ]
    return jenkins
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's a great answer!

Comment: do you happen to know which library covers Stage or Node level?

Comment: You're welcome, and thanks for the accepted answer. Regarding your question, I don't quite follow, can you explain more, or is it maybe a separate question?

Comment: this class CpsScript covers script and anything that can be used inside, but the jenkins pipeline consist from node->stage->script->etc, so i was thinking you might know which class covers stage or node blocks?

Comment: Aha, think I'm understanding your question, if you want to mock the behaviour of steps/blocks than those that I showed, then you just add them as map entries in the map returned by `mockCpsScript`, e.g. you can easily add an entry for the node step by adding `'node' : {arg -> ... }` to the returned map.

Comment: stage and node on the higher level from script block and seems like it's covered in other class that i can't find, it's not a part of CpsScript object

Comment: hey Jon, i tried to use it in Jenkins console, for some reason it complains about property steps - groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: steps for class: groovy.lang.Binding, do you know what might be the reason?

Comment: @tinySandy right, sorry, tiny error in my examples, forgot to override the `script` step. I've updated my answer! Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: hey Jon, quick question, i was also using this.currentBuild.description and this.params and it worked just fine, but if i try to mock it and make it a part of the CPSScript it says no such parameter, do you happen to know how to work around it?

Comment: I haven't figured that one out yet... If I do, I'll get back to you here...

Comment: @tinySandy, had the same problem with currentBuild today and found a solution. Have a look at the end of my update example.