# Why doesn't Groovy's power assert work in a Jenkins job

Tags: jenkins, groovy

[Power assertions](http://groovy-lang.org/testing.html#_power_assertions) work in the /script, but do not work in a Jenkinsfile driven job. 
Why?
Is there a way to get it to work?

In Jenkinsfile job:

```
assert 1 == 2

at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.assertFailed(InvokerHelper.java:404)
... wall of stack trace
```

In /script window

```
Assertion failed: 

assert 1 == 2
         |
         false
```

In this trivial example, it is easy to figure out what is going on. In practice, one or both of the operands of "==" will be a variable. In the /script version,
it will display the values (see the link above). In the Jenkinsfile console log you just get the assert statement as is with no hints.

Added after @daggett question:

```
node ()
  {
  stage('assert')
    {
    try 
      {
      two = 2
      assert 1==two 
      }
    catch(Throwable t)
      {
      println t
      error "assert failed"
      }
    }
  }
```

output:

```
Assertion failed: 

assert 1==two
```

Comment: what do you see in console for `try{ assert 1==2 }catch(Throwable t){println t}` ?

Comment: Assertion failed: assert 1==2

Comment: seems pipeline prints out multi-line strings incorrectly... and what if you do `println "Assertion failed: \n\nassert 1 == 2\n         |\n         false"`

Comment: What is your issue exactly ?

Comment: I am trying to test functions in a Jenkins library as part of the workflow for maintaining it. The DSL version of the asserts only reports failures, but does not show the values. This means jumping through hoops to figure out what each operand to the '==' operator is when asserts fail.

Comment: Oooo, you are heading down the Jenkins pipeline library testing rabbit hole, how fun! Note that it is possible to do the bulk of the testing as unit tests where all Jenkins parts and most notably the CPS processor has been mocked away, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/50221004/7509826. This would avoid the issue of power assert not working as the "unit" tests are executed using normal groovy. Only problem is that you also need (from my experience) system/integration tests running in Jenkins, I guess there you will have to make due with what you get...

Answer (score 9):

Not possible as far as I can see. Jenkins pipeline groovy DSL uses custom CPS interpreter during interpretation of groovy. This means that it bypasses/overrides a lot of the standard implementation of groovy, and thus also the assert implementation. The assert implementation for Jenkins Pipeline CPS can be found [here](https://github.com/cloudbees/groovy-cps/blob/master/lib/src/main/java/com/cloudbees/groovy/cps/impl/AssertBlock.java#L38), while the real groovy implementation uses [this](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/master/src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/classgen/asm/AssertionWriter.java#L41) class during the assert evaluation in order to record values and print proper exception.

In order to get similar behaviour in Jenkins pipeline CPS one would either need to refactor the groovy code base and Jenkins CPS code or duplicate a lot of the functionality in the AssertionWriter class linked above.

Comment: It is starting to look like this should be an issue against Jenkins. This really should be easy.

Comment: Give it some time.  You're just ahead of the curve.

Comment: Agree, would be nice if Jenkins handled it the same way, I wouldn't say that is a bug, more like a limitation or missing feature. Feel free to write an issue over at https://issues.jenkins-ci.org, but as I said in my answer, it will probably be quite tricky to implement.

Answer (score 1):

Old discussion but now, 2023-11-07, this pipeline execute the `assert`:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Assert') {
            steps {
                script {
                    assert 1 == 2
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And, as expected, Jenkins fails and displays:

```
Also:   org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.actions.ErrorAction$ErrorId: 89ab84d9-9d75-4bec-b0c5-b63db969d0d1
hudson.remoting.ProxyException: Assertion failed: 

assert 1 == 2

    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.assertFailed(InvokerHelper.java:420)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.assertFailed(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:663)
...
```

Note the `script{}` inside the `steps{}` to have `assert` that works.

Answer (score -1):

This is an example of a hack that sort of works:

```
def ASSERT_EQ (def arg1, def arg2)
  {
  if (arg1 != arg2)
    {
    println ('arg1 = ' + arg1 + " " + arg1.getClass())
    println ('arg2 = ' + arg2 + " " + arg2.getClass())
    }
  assert arg1 == arg2
  }
```

It is not nearly as robust as the normal groovy power assert.

Comment: FYI: The above example still doesn't work in declarative pipeline.